# Setting UITableViewCell clipsToBounds = false in an insetGrouped UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Here is the design I'm looking to achieve.

[image: Design]

Seems easy enough to use a `UITableView` with `UITableView.Style.insetGrouped` and three sections. Then for the row in the second section, I figured I'd apply the old trick of overriding the cell's `setFrame:` method to inset the trailing edge, add a button outside the bounds, set `clipsToBounds = false` on both the cell and the cell's content view, and override `point(inside:with:)` to make sure the button is tappable.

However, the cell's `clipsToBounds` property always reverts to true and the button is not visible. Even if I subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `clipsToBounds` to always return false, the button is still not visible. However, if I change the table view's style to `plain` or `grouped`, the button is visible and tappable.

Obviously, there are other ways to achieve this design such as having each "section" be its own table view or setting my own view with corner radius to the cell's `backgroundView`. But, why does my approach not work specifically for the `insetGrouped` style and is there any workaround?

```swift
class InsetButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var buttonStack: UIStackView!
    
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get { super.frame }
        set {
            guard let buttonStack = buttonStack else { super.frame = newValue; return }
            var insetFrame = newValue
            insetFrame.size.width -= buttonStack.frame.width
            super.frame = insetFrame
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        clipsToBounds = false
        contentView.clipsToBounds = false
    }
    
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        frame.union(buttonStack.frame).contains(point)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple's implementation of inset grouped tables require the rounded cells to have clipsToBounds enabled. This because the corner effect is achieved by settings the cornerRadius on the cell layer. Without cropping you would not actually see the corner effect at all.

Please note that this only applies to cells that have corners, i.e. the first and last cell of each section.
If you disable clipsToBounds to a cell that is in the middle then the property will remain disabled.